# What's an elegant way to compare one-hot label results?

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to calculate the 'accuracy' of one-hot label encoded tensors, such that for the following example, I'd get 0.5.

```
tensor([[0,0,1], [1,0,0]]) == tensor([[0,0,1], [0,1,0]])
```

I want to know what proportion of the predictions are correctly labelled.

What's the most elegant way to achieve this with a pytorch tensor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly. You want all values to match for each row to be considered as a correct prediction then it should be something like this.

```
(tensor([[0,0,1], [1,0,0]]) == tensor([[0,0,1], [0,1,0]])).all(dim=1).float().mean()
```

Comment: Exactly right! Thank you! Out of curiosity; is there an out-of-the-box function for this comparison?

Comment: Hmm i dont think so. I dont recall sklearn providing such a function too.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [`torchmetrics`](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#torchmetrics-documentation) for computing metrics out-of-the-box:

```
import torch
import torchmetrics

a = torch.tensor([[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]])
b = torch.tensor([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]])

torchmetrics.functional.accuracy(a, b, subset_accuracy=True)
```

output:

```
tensor(0.5000)
```